# Updated items on recyclerView are lost when view pager is used

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

When i change `recyclerView` data of one tab,data is being reflected(working fine), but when i switch to other tabs and go back to updated tab , the updated items on `recyclerView` are lost .how to notify `viewpager` adapter that i have changed data in `recyclerAdapter`.

[image]

Comment: Are you using same List<Data> to display data in all tabs?

Comment: Try using setOffscreenPageLimit to viewpager

Comment: Post code for better understanding of the problem.

Comment: That depends on how you are fetching and later updating your adapter's **datasource**. Putting a snippet of your adapter's code might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, ViewPager loads the next and previous (if any) fragment on initialization and if you will go to the second tab it will load 3rd automatically. You need to use:

```
viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);//3 is the limit not refreshing the fragment till 2 swipes
```

Hope this will solve your problem.